# Laravel Route /{username} in form action

Tags: php, forms, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I'm currently dealing with Image Upload in Laravel-5.3.
My "profile page" routes are defined as:

```
/* GET request to show the profile page */

Route::get('/{username}', [
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@getProfile',
    'as'   => 'profile.index',

]);

/* POST request to update the Avatar (display pic) */

Route::post('/{username}', [
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@updateAvatar',
    'as'   => 'profile.index',
]);
```

Thus, the profile URL pretty much looks like `example.com/john` (let "john" be the username)

In the form though, I have to define the "action".

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="POST">
```

How can I define the route in the form action so that the users are redirected to their own respective routes; something like " `example.com/john` ".

I guess I can't directly define `<form action="/{username}">` as I'll be taken to `example.com/{username}` instead.

Comment: you have 2 routes with the same route name.

Answer (score 0):

If you need route for current user you can do something like:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{ url(Auth::user()->name) }}" method="POST">
```

UPD: for named route you can using `route` helper

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{ route('profile.index', ['username' => 'username_here']); }}" method="POST">
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are naming the route, you can use that name to define the URL through the [**route()**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#urls) helper, passing an array of parameters as the second argument.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" 
      method="POST"
      action="{{ route('profile.index', [
          'username' => Auth::user()->name
      ]) }}">
```